# change the css order property with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url

I would like to change the order of the divs on a page, using an if statement in jQuery. The if statment is based on the url parameter. I am using the css 'order' property. I think this is the best way to do this, but I am not sure.

**IN A NUTSHELL:**

> If I type section03 in the url, then section03 should show first on
>   the page
>
> If I type section02 in the url, then section02 should show first on
>   the page and so on.

**CODE SAMPLE**:

```
if (dynamicContent == 'section02') {
  $('#section02').css('order', 1);
  //sort divs by order
  $('#wrapper').append($('#wrapper 
  .dynamiccontent').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('order') - b.getAttribute('order');
  }));
}
```

**Example**:
https://jsfiddle.net/stopdaydreaming/jjageca7/

Comment: I guess you’d want to use `setAttribute(name, value)` in JavaScript or `attr(name, value)` in jQuery to set the order attribute on the tags.

Comment: There is no "order" attribute in HTML. Are you thinking of the flexbox CSS property "order"?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Where does OP say "HTML order"?

Comment: I am using order in the HTML this way:  <div id="section03" class="dynamic-content" order="3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 25%">
          <p><small>module03:</small></p>
          <h3>content goes here</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: thank you @NoImaginationGuy that worked!